# how to insert ads in the middle of the list category archive page?

Tags: wordpress, optimization, data-structures, arraylist, insertion

guys ... I get a problem here ...

I want to insert ads in the middle category archive page,
Ok, this is the situation:

In the category archive page of my theme (Fastheme) I have 1 view's, if you select one of the list of categories: example "featured"

Total output Category the selected (10 Posts)
Display List Category Archive page.

> Display Category "featured"  (1 Posts)
>
> Display Category "featured"  (2 Posts)
>
> Display Category "featured"  (3 Posts)
>
> Display Category "featured"  (4 Posts)
>
> **<-- Position Ads -->**
>
> Display Category "featured"  (5 Posts)
>
> Display Category "featured"  (6 Posts)
>
> Display Category "featured"  (7 Posts)
>
> Display Category "featured"  (8 Posts)
>
> Display Category "featured"  (9 Posts)
>
> Display Category "featured"  (10 Posts)

The following is the code that is on my Category Archive Page:

```
<div class="posta">
    <h1><?php if(is_category()) { ?> <?php single_cat_title(''); ?> News and Pictures
        <?php } elseif (is_day()) { ?><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_month()) { ?> <?php the_time('F, Y'); ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_tag()) { ?> <?php single_tag_title(''); ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_year()) { ?> <?php the_time('Y'); ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_author()) { ?> Author
        <?php } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?> Blog Archives
        <?PHP } ?><?php  if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { echo ' ('; echo __('page') . ' ' . get_query_var('paged');   echo ')';  } ?>
    </h1>
</div>

        <?php $postcounter = 1; if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : $postcounter = $postcounter + 1; the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; $the_post_ids = get_the_ID(); ?>

                <div class="post post-<?php echo $postCount ;?>" style="width:755px;float:right"><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/thumb.php'); ?>
                    <div class="posttitle">
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tags"><?php the_time('M jS Y') ?> | <?php comments_popup_link('0 Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></div>
                    <?php echo excerpt(50); ?><?php if ( is_home() || is_category() || is_tag()) : ?>&nbsp;<?php endif; ?>
                    <p class="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">...learn more</a></p>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
            <div class="notfound"></div>
            <div class="post"><center><h2>404 Not Found</h2></center></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

please help me.!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the ad displayed in the middle you can do something like this:

```
<div class="posta">
    <h1><?php if(is_category()) { ?> <?php single_cat_title(''); ?> News and Pictures
        <?php } elseif (is_day()) { ?><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_month()) { ?> <?php the_time('F, Y'); ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_tag()) { ?> <?php single_tag_title(''); ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_year()) { ?> <?php the_time('Y'); ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_author()) { ?> Author
        <?php } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?> Blog Archives
        <?PHP } ?><?php  if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { echo ' ('; echo __('page') . ' ' . get_query_var('paged');   echo ')';  } ?>
    </h1>
</div>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $the_post_ids = get_the_ID(); ?>

        <?php if (floor($post_count/2) == $current_post) : ?>

            // Your add code here

        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="post post-<?php echo $postCount ;?>" style="width:755px;float:right"><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/thumb.php'); ?>
            <div class="posttitle">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="tags"><?php the_time('M jS Y') ?> | <?php comments_popup_link('0 Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></div>
            <?php echo excerpt(50); ?><?php if ( is_home() || is_category() || is_tag()) : ?>&nbsp;<?php endif; ?>
            <p class="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">...learn more</a></p>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
        <div class="notfound"></div>
        <div class="post"><center><h2>404 Not Found</h2></center></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

`$current_post` is holds the index of the current post in the loop

`$post_count` is the total displayed post in the current page

Read https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query for more information.

Comment: okay, I'll try it once, and I see references you have provided. Thank you for your participation. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Vivek Manglani.
After I used the code you provided, that happens here is ...

```
Display Category "featured" (1 Posts)
// Your code here add
Display Category "featured" (2 Posts)
// Your code here add
Display Category "featured" (3 Posts)
// Your code here add
Display Category "featured" (4 Posts)
/ / Your code here add
Display Category "featured" (5 Posts)
/ / Your code here add
```

and so on.
what if want to make it like this?

```
Display Category "featured" (1 Posts)
Display Category "featured" (2 Posts)
Display Category "featured" (3 Posts)
Display Category "featured" (4 Posts)

<- Position Ads ->

Display Category "featured" (5 Posts)
Display Category "featured" (6 Posts)
Display Category "featured" (7 Posts)
Display Category "featured" (8 Posts)
Display Category "featured" (9 Posts)
Display Category "featured" (10 Posts)
```

please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $the_post_ids = get_the_ID(); $i ++?>
<?php if ($i == 5) : ?>
            // Your Ad Code Here
<?php endif; ?>
```